# Upload Images from Array to Firebase & Get Download URL

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload an array of images to firebase storage and return an array of images so i can add it to the database as a post.

i have tried to upload the image then the post but the code is executing twice if i have two images and inserting two entries into the database. I am using the function below to upload an image.

```
var data = [[String:String]]

for image in data {

  uploadMedia {
      // returns single urls 
  }
}

    func uploadMedia(completion: @escaping (_ url: String?) -> Void) { 
    let storageRef = 
    FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("myImage.png")
    if let uploadData = 
    UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.myImageView.image!) {
        storageRef.put(uploadData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("error")
                completion(nil)
            } else {
                completion((metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString)!)) 
                // your uploaded photo url.
            }
       }
    }
```

I want the function to return an array of images such as [imageURL:"XYZ" , size : "Size"]

Comment: That doesn't look like a good way of uploading an image unless you want to name every asset the same.

Comment: just an example